# Django relationship in manyToMany models, object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a problem with creating relationship in m2m models.

models.py

```
class ECG(models.Model):
    procedure= models.ManyToManyField('Procedure')
    ...
class Procedure(models.Model):
    basic_info= models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
def newECG(request, procedure_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewECG(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            info = IncomingProcedure.objects.get(id=procedure_id)
            form.procedure.add(info) #HERE IS A PROBLEM
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/system/')
    else:
        form = NewECG()
    return render(request, 'system/ecg.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class NewECG(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ECG
        exclude = ['procedure']
        # fields = '__all__'
        fields = [ ... ] # rest fields, except procedure
```

`Procedure` already exists. I need to create `newECG` in relation with procedure. ECG form is saving in db. Problem is when i want to use `add()` function.

```
ERROR :'NewECG' object has no attribute 'procedure', exception location: views.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot a step:

```
def newECG(request, procedure_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewECG(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ecg = form.save()
            info = IncomingProcedure.objects.get(id=procedure_id)
            ecg.procedure.add(info) #HERE IS A PROBLEM
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/system/')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ModelForm` instance does not have the `procedure` attribute that is defined on the model. The `ECG` model instance, however, which is returned by the form's `save(...)` method, does have it:

```
ecg_instance = form.save()
info = IncomingProcedure.objects.get(id=procedure_id)
# info = Procedure.objects.get(id=procedure_id)
ecg_instance.procedure.add(info)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you are trying to add `IncomingProcedure.objects` to your `from` in **views.py**

If you want save it on your database, Should simply do this:

***views.py***

```
# ... Your codes:
M = form.save()  # save your class instance to M variable
info = IncomingProcedure.objects.get(id=procedure_id)
M.procedure.add(info) # save procedure instance to your object(An ECG model instance)
```